# Moprhia - Add dynamic attributes to Java object before saving in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

If i insert into **MongoDB** (using **Morphia**) the following Java object:

```
public class Developer{
    private String username;
    private String email;

    //getter and setter
}
```

the result is:

```
{
    "username" : "John",
    "email" : "spamme@mail.com"
}
```

I would like to insert further informations in addition to object variables (eg. developing language skills) **dynamically** and the result should be:

```
{
     "username" : "John",
     "email" : "spamme@mail.com"
     "java" : "excellent",
     "sql" : "good",
     "jquery" : "good"   
     ...     
}
```

do you know how to add dynamic attribute using Morphia?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution would be to use a `Map` to store those fields.  It would push those "dynamic" fields down underneath the map field but if the shape of the document is flexible, that would be the simplest solution by far.